# Summing a map of doubles into an aggregated BigDecimal with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, sum, java-stream, bigdecimal

I'm trying to use the Java 8 Stream API *mapToDouble* method like so:

```
BigDecimal totalCost = order.getOrderlineList().stream()
    .mapToDouble(Orderline::getPrice)
    .sum();
```

The problem is that `Orderline::getPrice` returns a `BigDecimal`, not a `Double`. Hence the attempt above fails to compile (*Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.math.BigDecimal to doubele*).

Seeing that `Orderline#price` is a `BigDecimal`, how can I use the Stream API (and either `mapToDouble` or something similar) to get my `totalCost`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `BigDecimal`s using [`BigDecimal.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-) instead of converting them to double and back again to avoid rounding errors. To sum all prices you can use [`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = order.getOrderLines().stream()
        .map(OrderLine::getPrice)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

From the docs of `Stream.reduce()`:

> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the provided identity value and an associative accumulation function, and returns the reduced value. This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> T result = identity;
> for (T element : this stream)
>     result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
> return result;
> ```

`BigDecimal::add` is a short form of `(a, b) -> a.add(b)`, which simply returns `a + b`. For addition the identity element is `0` or `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, can you (or anyone!) please explain to me what the `reduce()` is doing there?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Yes of course, I updated my answer, hope it helps to understand. Feel free to ask for further clarification if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) with Java Streams, this will work:

```
BigDecimal totalCost = order.getOrderlineList().stream()
    .collect(Collectors2.summingBigDecimal(Orderline::getPrice));
```

You can also use the `Iterate` class to simplify the code slightly.

```
BigDecimal totalCost = Iterate.sumOfBigDecimal(order.getOrderlineList(), Orderline::getPrice)
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections